# save annotations using PDFtron

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pdftron

I am trying to save annotations to a file stored in Google Cloud Platform.I am using PDFtron. When I click on save annotations, it fails to save annotation and it returns a "400 error". Has someone faced similar issues while working with PDFtron ?

Answer (score 1):

By default WebViewer uses the serverUrl parameter of the WebViewer constructor for the server url end point for annotation loading/saving.

For example, if you are using our default lib/html5/annotationHandler.php then url would be something like the following.

`https://your.domain/webviewer/lib/html5/annotationHandler.php`

Then, for example if you trigger save of annotations (by doing alt-s) you should see a POST request to

`https://your.domain/webviewer/lib/html5/annotationHandler.php?did=webviewer_developer_guide`

See this guide for more info.

https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/getting-started-annotations.html